# In Microsoft Dynamics 365 F&O's X++, why doesn't this event reassign the value of CustTable.CustGroup?

Tags: error-handling, event-handling, variable-assignment, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I'm currently working my way through [Event Handlers in D365 with Example](https://www.d365snippets.com/2022/01/event-han.html).

As I understand this code:

```
class EventHandlerCustTable
{    
   
   [DataEventHandler(tableStr(CustTable), DataEventType::Inserted)]
   public static void CustTable_onInserted(Common sender, DataEventArgs e)
   {
       CustTable custTable = sender as CustTable;
       // 90 is the Customer group code for Intercompany Cutomer
       if(custTable.CustGroup=="90")
           
       {
           // 80 is the Customer group code for Other Customer
           custTable.CustGroup="80" ; 
           Global::error("Created Customer is an Intercompany Cutomer and will be added to the Customer Group Other Customer");
           
           // you can write your logic here.        
       }
 
      
   }
 
}
```

... when the value of `custTable.CustGroup` is "90", the value should be reset to "80" and the error message should appear.

However, when I execute the code, the value is *not* changed.
In fact, the screenshot of the article itself does not display this value as changed, though like my own local experience, the error message is in fact displayed.

So:

1. Why doesn't the value change?
2. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog article linked to in the question gets it almost right. However, the wrong event is used. The `onInserted` event is triggered after the record creation has already happened. This is why modifying fields in this event makes no sense in this case.

The event to use is `onInserting`, which is triggered while the record creation is happening.

Note that in the blog, they also first refer to the `onInserting` event:

> To understand this concept better, let's take the example of On
> Inserting Event Handler with Table.

But then in the "Example" section, they suddenly switch to the `onInserted` event.

The Microsoft documentation has a nice example for this event, see [Add methods to tables through extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/extensibility/add-method-table).